# Need help writing a query using WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a query to show staffid, staff full name, speciality id of all male staff.

```
SELECT staffid, firstname, lastname, specid, specname 
  FROM staff, staffspeciality, speciality     
 WHERE speciality.specid = staff_speciality.specid     
 WHERE staff.staffid = staff_speciality.staffid     
 WHERE gender = ‘M’;
```

> SQL> describe staff

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 FIRSTNAME                                          VARCHAR2(20)
 LASTNAME                                           VARCHAR2(20)
 ROLE                                               VARCHAR2(15)
 GENDER                                             CHAR(1)
 DATEJOINED                                         DATE
 DATELEFT                                           DATE
```

> SQL> describe specialty;

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SPECIALID                                 NOT NULL CHAR(4)
 SPECNAME                                           VARCHAR2(20)
 SPECNOTES                                          VARCHAR2(100)
```

> SQL> describe staff_speciality;

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 SPECID                                    NOT NULL CHAR(4)
 DATEQUALIFIED                             NOT NULL DATE
 VALIDTILLDATE                                      DATE
 DETAILS                                            VARCHAR2(100)
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.

Comment: I dont know how to use that, could you please shoe me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT staff.staffid, staff.firstname, staff.lastname, staff_speciality.specid, speciality.specname 
  FROM staff 
  JOIN staff_speciality
    ON staff.staffid = staff_speciality.staffid   
  JOIN speciality     
    ON speciality.specid = staff_speciality.specid         
 WHERE gender = ‘M’;
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "SPECIALTY"."SPECNAME": invalid identifier

Comment: its a typo sorry.. It's suppose to be `speciality.specname`. Check edited answer

Comment: Glad I could help @reece